# What's the difference between this two FULL XPATH?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, web-inspector, xidel

The link I used is [here](https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/XAU=)

My procedure of getting the "price" xpath are:

1. go to the link using chrome
2. use tool `inspect element`
3. search for the price number
4. then come into `<span class="QuoteStrip-lastPrice">some_numbers</span>`
5. right click the element, then select Copy Full XPATH
6. Then I'll get `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]`

Problem:
Two days ago before this thread, I was using the full xpath I got from chrome inspection, it working just fine in `xidel` without a problem. But now,

```
xidel -se '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]' ~/Desktop/document.html
```

or

```
xidel -se '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]' https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/XAU=
```

gives me no output...

but, user2703456 given me the "correct" full xpath as follow `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]`

it solved the problem, however, I still confused. when I check both full xpath pointing at the same element, exact same element. why? why it was working before, but now wont?

[XPath inspection snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrrEe.png)

Comment: Xpaths reveal structure changed at `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div`. The not working one ends with `dev[2]`

Comment: i know dev[2] is not working, but why. If I check manually, `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div` pointing at `#MainContentContainer > div > div.BadgeGroup-badgeGroup` while div[2] should be pointing at `#MainContentContainer > div > div.QuotePageBuilder-row` it is where in it, contain the result that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's content comes dynamicly, and somehow the server or javascript changes html.

To overcome this problems i would use not the copied XPath but rely more on a combination of @class en @id attributes i.e. like this:

```
//*[@id='quote-page-strip']//*[@class='QuoteStrip-lastPrice']
```

Comment: I think the element stays static, the live visit vs. downloaded(by curl, etc.) has the same element structures, and by processing the downloaded html offline also has the same result.